# Is it possible to copy data from a cell into a macro?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written data in a cell that is updated by a macro - it appends a reference depending on what somebody has called a new sheet.

In Cell A1 I end up with macro code that is updated with the new sheet name. Currently users have to copy this text and open another macro and paste the code in, however they keep doing it wrong and breaking it.

What I would like to do is write a macro to copy the contents of Cell A1 and paste them into the original macro.

If it possible to do this?

Comment: What do you really want to do ... use s sheet name given in a cell inside a piece of VBA code?

Comment: The value is available dynamically via; `Sheets("SheetName").Range("A1").value`

Answer (score 0):

Based on a suggestion at the [MrExcel.com forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/75489-change-visual-basic-applications-code-visual-basic-applications-code.html#post364491):

```
Sub aaa()
    For i = 1 To Application.VBE.CodePanes.Count
    Application.VBE.CodePanes(i).CodeModule.ReplaceLine 1, "alert('Yo')  ' New code"
Next i
```

Comment: I will agree with MikeD's comment above, though... while this may be possible, I'm sure there's a better way to engineer the solution.

Comment: Sorry I tried to keep it brief as it's quite a convoluted process!! I have one big macro that runs updates on some of the sheets in a spreadsheet. These all have a two letter prefix such as HD or ER which relates to the clients name. This "Month" macro runs these updates by referencing each sheet.

Comment: @HazelPopham - Well, you can try the above. If it works you can upvote and/or mark as correct. Hope this helps!

Comment: A macro runs & updates on some of the sheets These have a two letter prefix such as HD or ER which relates to the clients name. This "Month" macro runs these updates by referencing each sheet

The 2nd macro "New Client" creates a new sheet & asks the user to input a new abbreviation. The new client is created & "Monthly" code for this new client populated in cell A1 of a sheet & updates the sheet referenced in the code with the abbreviation

However I would like to take this newly created code that resides in cell A1 & paste it into the "Monthly" macro so this will be updated going forward

Comment: How does the monthly macro knows the client names.. "HD.....", "ER....."  Does it maintain the list in some place in the file itself.  If yes, then just write a macro to add it to that list, instead of providing the name during the execution of Monthly macro.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to your question but I'm just offering some information. I would suggest that you don't have users create a macro in each sheet.  You can access anything on any sheet from a module.  I am not sure what you whole process is but you could think of it more along the lines of looking for the sheets you want to change.

```
Public sub ProcessSheets()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    'Loop through all the worksheets in the workbook.
    For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

        'Activate the current sheet, if you need to.
        Set ws = Worksheets(iIndex)
        ws.Activate

        'Check the name of the worksheet.
        If Left(ws.Name, 2) = "HD" or Left(ws.Name, 2) = "ER" Then

            'Call the function that changes the worksheet here.
            'Maybe feed it the worksheet name.
            UpdateWorksheet ws.Name

        End if

    Next iIndex
End Sub
```